# Why do strings given to the RegExp constructor need to be double escaped?

Tags: javascript, regex

In the regex below, `\s` denotes a space character.  I imagine the regex parser, is going through the string and sees `\` and knows that the next character is special.

But this is not the case as double escapes are required.

Why is this?

```
var res = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + foo).test(moo);
```

Is there a concrete example of how a single escape could be mis-interpreted as something else?

Comment: Remember, it's not that Java or the Regexp constructor need clarification, it's the compiler (or parser).

Comment: To add to the already-correct answers: note that if you write a RegExp literal in JavaScript, you *don't* need to escape the backslash, as you would suspect: `/(\s|^)/`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329801/1225328.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are constructing the regular expression by passing a string to the RegExp constructor.

`\` is an escape character in string literals.

The `\` is consumed by the string literal parsing…

```js
const foo = "foo";
const string = '(\s|^)' + foo;
console.log(string);
```

… so the data you pass to the RegEx compiler is a plain `s` and not `\s`.

You need to escape the `\` to express the `\` as data instead of being an escape character itself.

Comment: That pertains to both regular string literals as well as template string literals.

Answer (score 24):

Inside the code where you're creating a string, the backslash is a javascript escape character first, which means the escape sequences like `\t`, `\n`, `\"`, etc. will be translated into their javascript counterpart (tab, newline, quote, etc.), and that will be made a part of the string. Double-backslash represents a single backslash in the actual string itself, so if you want a backslash in the string, you escape that first.

So when you generate a string by saying `var someString = '(\\s|^)'`, what you're really doing is creating an actual string with the value `(\s|^)`.

Answer (score 11):

The Regex needs a string representation of `\s`, which in JavaScript can be produced using the literal `"\\s"`.

Here's a live example to illustrate why `"\s"` is not enough:

```js
alert("One backslash:          \s\nDouble backslashes: \\s");
```

Note how an extra `\` before `\s` changes the output.

Answer (score 9):

As has been said, inside a string literal, a backslash indicates an escape sequence, rather than a literal backslash character, but the RegExp constructor often needs literal backslash characters in the string passed to it, so the code should have `\\`s to represent a literal backslash, *in most cases*.

A problem is that double-escaping metacharacters is tedious. There is one way to pass a string to `new RegExp` without having to double escape them: use the `String.raw` template tag, an ES6 feature, which allows you to write a string that will be parsed by the interpreter *verbatim*, without any parsing of escape sequences. For example:

```js
console.log('\\'.length);           // length 1: an escaped backslash
console.log(`\\`.length);           // length 1: an escaped backslash
console.log(String.raw`\\`.length); // length 2: no escaping in String.raw!
```

So, if you wish to keep your code readable, and you have many backslashes, you may use `String.raw` to type only *one* backslash, when the pattern requires a backslash:

```js
const sentence = 'foo bar baz';
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\bfoo\sbar\sbaz\b`);
console.log(regex.test(sentence));
```

**But there's a better option.** Generally, there's not much good reason to use `new RegExp` unless you need to dynamically create a regular expression from existing variables. Otherwise, you should use regex literals instead, which do not require double-escaping of metacharacters, and do not require writing out `String.raw` to keep the pattern readable:

```js
const sentence = 'foo bar baz';
const regex = /\bfoo\sbar\sbaz\b/;
console.log(regex.test(sentence));
```

Best to only use `new RegExp` when the pattern must be created on-the-fly, like in the following snippet:

```js
const sentence = 'foo bar baz';
const wordToFind = 'foo'; // from user input

const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b${wordToFind}\b`);
console.log(regex.test(sentence));
```

Comment: If there is a `/` in your regular expression, you should also use `new RegExp`, not just in the on-the-fly case.

Comment: Why, there's no need? Just like other special characters, just escape it with a backslash. `/foo\/bar/` will match `foo/bar`

Comment: As you wrote earlier, double escaping metacharacters is tedious. In this case, the `new RegExp` is the only way when you want your code to work with any regular expression without the need for additional escaping.

Answer (score 7):

\ is used in Strings to escape special characters. If you want a backslash in your string (e.g. for the \ in \s) you have to escape it via a backslash. So \ becomes \\ .

EDIT: Even had to do it here, because \\ in my answer turned to \.