# javascript replace \/ or /\ to single slash /

Tags: javascript, replace

I know alot of answers are out there for string replace in javascript, but I can't find one for \/ to /. please help me out on this or send me some link to how to write regular expressions in so to replace. Thank you

Comment: Whats your input and whats your output?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Also with the input/output it's good form to see the code that you have tried that is not working.

Comment: look like input is JSON ... or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a [backslash is used as an escape character](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4), you'll need to escape it:

```
str = str.replace("\\/", "/");
```

The above replaces `\/` with `/`. In general, anywhere you use a backslash in a string, you probably need to escape it. So, to replace `/\` with `/`, you'd use:

```
str = str.replace("/\\", "/");
```

These will, of course, only replace one instance in the string. To replace multiple instances, use a regular expression with the `g` (global) modifier:

```
str = str.replace(/\\\/|\/\\/g, "/")
```

Here, because forward slashes have meaning as regex terminators, you're having to escape the forward slash as well as the backslash. The alternative is to use the `RegExp` class:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\\\/|/\\\\", "g"), "/")
```

In *this* one, you're having to escape the backslash twice — once to escape it in the string, and once in the regex. ([Here's a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped).)