# How to decode "\/" in strings

Tags: c#, string-decoding

I am parsing a source that frequently contains `/` encoded as `\/`. For example, `https://` is encoded as `https:\/\/`.

What is the name of this encoding?  It appreas to be used when sending json in HTML. It is a large document and `/` to `\/` mapping probably isn't the only one used. What is the c# function to decode it?

Comment: Does the source document contain the literal characters \ followed by /?  If not, this is just how [string escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string) works.

Comment: That's not an encoding that I'm familiar with.  And, it's not something you generally see in a string with *escaped* characters.  Where is this string coming from?

Comment: What exactly is this "source"? Please provide more context. Slashes are rarely escaped or encoded, and even more rarely escaped in that way, although you *will* see that in regexes where the language uses the `/` character as the delimiter (e.g. Perl, JavaScript).

Comment: I haven't found any literal \ characters. The document is a json response from a website. Using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"\/\/") seems to do the job

Comment: Can you show an example of that response? Maybe someone will recognize it. If you don't know that it's a regex or that the extent of escaping matches that of regex, it might do something you neither expect nor want with an input you haven't seen yet.

Comment: Perhaps you should add more details to the question (like the file type, where it came from, and sample file contents). And if you've found a solution, there is nothing wrong with answering your own question so others can learn from it.

Comment: `'\/'` is not recognized as a escape string in C#... Found that, first Google result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930687/javascript-replace-or-to-single-slash

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"\/\/")` seems to do the job.