# What does the regex "/\\*{2,}/" mean?

Tags: regex

I'm kinda new to regex, and specifically, I don't understand there are 2 backslashes? I mean, I know the second one is to escape the character "*", but what does the first backslash do?

Well I'm passing this regex expression to the php function preg_match(), and I'm trying to find strings that include 2 or more consecutive "*".

Comment: What program is this regex written for, and how is it being passed to that program?

Comment: The second ``\`` doesn't escape the `*` character. The first ``\`` escapes the second ``\``. It means 0 or more slashes.

Comment: This probably should be `/\*{2,0}/`. [Then it works](https://regex101.com/r/bE5oF6/1).

Comment: It can be a valid regex: `String regex = "/\\*{2,}/"; //regex: /\*{2,}/`

Comment: You should tag this question with [tag:php].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regex is invalid syntax.

You have this piece:

```
*{2,}
```

Which basically would read: `match n-times, 2 or more times`.

---

The following regex:

```
/\\*.{2,}/
```

Is the simplest and closest regex to the one you have, which would read as:
`match 0 or more '\' and 2 or more characters that aren't newlines`

If you are talking about the string itself, is may be interpreted as 2 things:

- `/\\*{2,}/`
  Read as: `match a single \ and another \ n-times 2 times or more`
  This is invalid syntax
- `/\*{2,}\`
  Read as `match 2 or more *`
  This is valid syntax

It all varies, depending on the escape character.

---

### Edit:

Since the question was updated to show which language and engine it is being used, I've updated to add the following information:

You have to pass the regex as `'/\*{2,}/'` **OR** as `"/\\*{2,}/"` (watch the quotes).

Both are very similar, except that single quotes (`''`) only support the following escape sequences:

- `\'` - Produces `'`
- `\\`- Produces `\`

Double-quoted strings are treated differently in PHP. And they support almost any escape sequence, like:

- `\"` - Produces `"`
- `\'` - Produces `'`
- `\\` - Produces `\`
- `\x<2-digit hex number>` - Same as `chr(0x<2-digit hex number>)`
- `\0` - Produces a `null` char
- `\1` - Produces a control char (same as `chr(1)`)
- `\u<4-digit hex number>` - Produces an UTF-8 character
- `\r` - Produces a newline on old OSX
- `\n` - Produces a newline on Linux/newer OSX/Windows (when writting a file without `b`)
- `\t` - Produces a tab
- `\<number>` or `\0<number>` - Same as `\x`, but the numbers are in octal (e.g.:  `"\75"` and `"\075"` produce `=`)
- ... (some more that I probably forgot) ...
- `\<anything>` - Produces `<anything>`

Read more about this on https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: AFAIK it is valid, but doesn't do much

Comment: Please note, that OP is not showing us a regex, but a regex string, that needs to have the escape character escaped. See my answer.

Comment: @PeeHaa You can test on https://regex101.com/ and http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex. Both will barf when you throw that bad boy.

Comment: I see. What engine are they on? Because rubular happily runs with it http://rubular.com/r/HcUYkFkAfE

Comment: To answer my own question. They all error. Even the PCRE one

Comment: @PeeHaa With the new edit, I think I nailed the answer.

Comment: Haha thanks man but what difference does it make to have "" vs. ' '? One is string and the other is, well, char?

Comment: @theOneAndOnlyFerris `""` will parse all character escapes and variables. While `''` won't. Using `''` will only detect the following escape sequences: `\'` and '\\'. All the others are only available with `""` (and heredocs). You can read more on https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Is it a string literal written in a program and if so which one? The double backslash may be to escape the escape char so that this regex matches at least 2 `*` star characters.

In JavaScript for example you need to escape the `\` so that your string literal can express it as data before you transform it into a regular expression when using the `RegExp` constructor. [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platrofm you're using, `"/\\*{2,}/"` may actually be a representation of a `/\*{2,'}/` string - this is because languages like Java treat `\` as an escape character, so to actually put that character within regex, you need to escape the character in regex string.

So, we have `/\*{2'}/` regex. `\*' matches the star character, and`{2,}` means at least two times. Your regex will match any two or more consecutive star characters.

Answer (score 0):

For **PHP** what you have with that regex is to repeat literally a `*` 2 or more times. You can easily see with with below diagram:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But when you have to code it in PHP you have to escape the backslash (with a backslash) to use it in string. For instance:

```
$re = "/\\*{2,}/"; 
$str = "..."; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Actually, it depends on the quotes. If you run `'/\\*{2,}/'` it will be different than running `"/\\*{2,}/"`. The first will error-out, while the last will work fine. (check it on my answer)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel very nice, thank you