# how to use RegExp properly

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to replace '$$$' with space using JavaScript. simple as that.

I have the following code:

```
var splitSign = '$$$';
var string = 'hello$$$how$$$are$$$you';
var regex = new RegExp(splitSign,'g');
var res = string.replace(regex,' ');
console.info(res);
```

the result is the string not modified! any ideas why ?

Comment: The `$` is a special regex character (end of line). Escape it, `\$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `regex` for this, you can use `split` and `join`. This will be **faster** than `regex`.

```
string.split(splitSign).join(' ');
```

`split` will split the text by `$$$` and return array. `join` will join the elements of the array by space and return string.

Comment: replace only replaces the first occurrence in the string

Answer (score 1):

`$` has a special meaning in the context of a regex, it marks the end of a line/string.

You have to escape it:

```
var splitSign = '\\$\\$\\$';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `$`.. since it is a special character in regex (meaning end of the string)

```
var splitSign = '\\$\\$\\$';    (if creating new RegExp)
```

Otherwise just use:

```
string.replace(/\$\$\$/g,' ');
```

Code:

```js
var splitSign = '\\$\\$\\$';
var string = 'hello$$$how$$$are$$$you';
var regex = new RegExp(splitSign,'g');
var res = string.replace(regex,' ');
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special meta character in regular expressions. It indicates the end of the string in the same way that `^` indicates the beginning.

In order to use these special characters, you have to escape them by preceding them with a backslash - this will result in the regex engine using the character literally and not parsing it as a special meta character. [However because you are using the `RegExp` constructor you'll need to double escape the special meta characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)

```
var splitSign = '\\$\\$\\$';
```

As was mentioned in other answers, what you are trying to do is easily accomplished *without regular expressions*. A simple `string.replace` would suffice here. If you want to replace multiple instances, you can provide the `g` flag to specify a global match.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

as i explained... string.replace without RegExp only changes the first occurrence in a string.

i found the following answer:
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

it has exactly what I need.

first.. auto escaping a string:

```
function escapeRegExp(string) { 
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

and then the replace function

```
function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
 return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);  
}
```