# Issues with Regex evaluation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My array consists of thousands of values and I need to get the '[State]' string out of it. 
I use regex for fetching various strings (from the same array) and they all work fine (for instance the following:

`'^\/\/[ ]{1}[0-9]{3,4}')`.

...so in order to get the mentioned '[State]' I created the following Regex:

```
'^\[State\]'
```

And it works fine in 
[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/v7sLE9/1)
...but as soon as I pass this regex in my javascript code:

```
var reg = new RegExp(searchElement);
```

and then match test it:

```
if (reg.test(file[el]))
```

I get other things returned like: [Test]... so obviously something's wrong with the expression. As mentioned other expressions work flawlessly... And I don't understand why it works in the online regex tester and it doesn't in my code...

Comment: Once you write it as `'^\\[State\\]'`, and pass to `RegExp` constructor, it will work.

Comment: Yes! Thanks Wiktor! Why double escape though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17863158/3832970