# how to restrict input of float values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regex which matches an inputs like:
`1234.789`
`12`
`123.02`

that is, maximum `4` digits on the left side of `.` and maximum `3` on right of `.`

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBF4GG9O5PQV) is what I have tried.

```js
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("input").keypress(function(e){
         var patt = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,4}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?$");
         var val = this.value + e.key;
         debugger;
    if (!patt.test(val)){
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="number">
```

Comment: Double escape special chars in the constructor notation. See [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped) However, use a regex literal: `var patt = /^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{0,3})?$/;`

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you tried? If yes, what is it?

Comment: The regex is working fine, I think, the problem is how you are trying to restric the values. Doing `e.preventDefault();` will not cause to "undo"

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,4}){0,1}$
```

You can check in the below:

[Regular Expression](http://rubular.com/r/YDfHr5T5sQ)