# ng-pattern / ng-show AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am actually got a angular form and some input inside. The purpose is to upload files in a cloud. So, I got an input for a directory path which could contain some sub-directories. So I got a regex on my JS in a scope like this: `$scope.regex = "^[^\/]\S+$";`

this regex would accept any characters if its not a "/" at first character.

and here's my angular code:

`<input name="directory" id="directory" type="text" class="form-control" ng-pattern="regex" ng-model="directoryName" placeholder="Enter a directory name"/>`

`<span class="error" ng-show="uploaderForm.directory.$error.pattern">directory path can't start by a "/"</span>`

Normally, with this regex, this path should be success:

```
directory/subdirectories/filename...
```

and this one shouldn't:

```
/directory/subdirectories/filename...
```

But my problem is that when i'm writing something like : test/subtest/blablabla, I got the ng-show error...

Note that my input can also be a single char, like `a`.

Comment: And if you use `$scope.regex = "^[^/]\\S+$";`?

Comment: Am I not using it with the ng-pattern="regex" ?

Comment: No, you have `\S`. You must double the backslashes.

Comment: Oh, ye sorry i'm blind.. it works but it is still a problem, if i want to write just a letter, it cant accept it. i mean if i enter "a" i got the error

Comment: Use `$scope.regex = "^[^/]\\S*$";`. It will allow 1 or more chars and the first one cannot be `/`. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Nice man, it works ! thank you :)

Comment: Try `$scope.regex = /^[^\/]\S+$/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$scope.regex = "^[^/]\\S*$";
```

Or its equivalent regex literal notation:

```
$scope.regex = /^[^\/]\S*$/;
```

The first issue is solved with doubling the backslashes. To define a literal `\` in JS string literal, you need to double it. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped).

The second problem is solved with replacing `+` (1 or more) with `*` (0 or more) quantifier. `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars, and `\S*` will match zero or  more chars other than whitespace.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\/]` - any char other than `/`
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Just in case you also want to allow an empty string, you may use a lookahead based regex:

```
$scope.regex = /^(?!\/)\S*$/;
```

Here, `(?!\/)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if the first char is `/`.

Comment: Won't using double backslash actually match `'\'` literally followed by a `S`?

Comment: @CinCout: No, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped

Comment: Ah. The constructor is getting a `string`. Perfect

Comment: Thanks man, and what if i just want to accept tilda, underscore, and letters at first please?

Comment: do I have to add other signs one by one after the "/" ?

Comment: *What if i just want to accept tilda, underscore, and letters at first* - then use [`/^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/g7hoPt/1).

Comment: ok, if i understood well, the combo of both should be: `/[^\/]^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$/`?

Comment: No, `[^\/]^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$` is a pattern that will never match any string. Just use `/^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$/`. `[~_a-zA-Z]` is a *positive* character class that matches `~`, `_`, or an ASCII letter. It can't match `/`. The `[^/]` is a *negated character class* due to `^` after `[` and that means it matches any char but `/`.

Comment: I used this one, but actually when im writing something like _blabla, I got an error, or I began with a _

Comment: Show me a fiddle.

Comment: what do you want to see ? I got the same code as bellow, just modified `$scope.regex = "^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$";` on JS side and try to write _directory/something and directory/something and  ~directory/something on my input and got the error

Comment: I told you to use `$scope.regex = /^[~_a-zA-Z]\S*$/;`. If you want to use a string literal, you must double escape the backslashes, `$scope.regex = "^[~_a-zA-Z]\\S*$";`. Re-read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped).

Comment: Yep, ok it works fine with string literal, i didn't get the difference between both. but now i got it :) Thanks man

Comment: Just [have a look here](https://jsfiddle.net/4x9jy39a/), it will be even clearer.