# Remove excessive blank lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an attempt to remove any excessive blank lines in string.

I'm trying to understand why second approach doesn't workfor lines which contains whitespace.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vr4c4zdj/3/).

```
var string = `
    foo



    bar (there are whitespaced lines between bar and baz. I replaced them with dots)
    ....................
    .......................
    ...........           
    baz
`;

// It works
string = string.replace(/^(\s*\n){2,}/gm, '\n');

// Why it doesn't work?
var EOL = string.match(/\r\n/gm) ? '\r\n' : '\n';
var regExp = new RegExp('^(\s*' + EOL + '){2,}', 'gm');
string = string.replace(regExp, EOL);

alert(string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\s` needs to be changed to `\\s`. Just putting `\s` is the same as `s`.

In strings (enclosed in quotes), the backslash has a special meaning. For example, `\n` is the newline character. There are a couple of others that you may or may not have heard of, e.g. `\b`, `\t`, `\v`. It would be bad language design choice to make only a few defined ones special, and consider the non-existent `\s` to be an actual backslash and an `s`, because it would be inconsistent, a source of errors, and not future-proof. That's why, when you want to have a backslash in a string, you escape the backslash to `\\`.

In your first example, you use `/` characters to delimit the regular expression. This is not considered a string bound by the above rules.

Comment: Not *all* `\s` need their backslash doubled. Which one(s) do, and why?

Comment: Possible answer why we need 2 backslashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped