# Regular Expression except [Value]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String and want to replace it with other String as given in mssqlFunctions object.

```
var mssqlFunctions = {
                DateDiff: "DATEDIFF",
                Abs: "ABS",
                y: 'year',
                m: 'minute'
            };
```

My String is: **DateDiff(m, Abs(23)[Emy()])**

This is my code to replace String

```
var regularExpression = new RegExp(Object.keys(mssqlFunctions).join("|"),"gi");

formula = formula.replace(regularExpression, function(matched){
  return mssqlFunctions[matched];
});
```

So it gives Output as **DATEDIFF(minute, ABS(23)[Eminuteyear()])**

But I don't want to replace string which is in []

So the Output which I want is

**DATEDIFF(minute, ABS(23)[Emy()])**

Comment: Isn't the expected output `DATEDIFF(minute, ABS(23)[Emy()])`? Are you sure the `()` should be gone?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match and capture a string between square brackets and check if the group matched. If the group matched, the match should fail, and you need to replace with the whole match (to put it back). Else, you may replace with the modified value.

Use

```js
var formula = "DateDiff(m, Abs(23)[Emy()])";
var mssqlFunctions = {
    DateDiff: "DATEDIFF",
    Abs: "ABS",
    y: 'year',
    m: 'minute'
};
var regularExpression = new RegExp("(\\[[^\\][]*])|" + Object.keys(mssqlFunctions).join("|"),"gi");

formula = formula.replace(regularExpression, function(matched, group1){
  return group1 ? matched : mssqlFunctions[matched];
});
console.log(formula); // => DATEDIFF(minute, ABS(23)[Emy()])
```

The `(\\[[^\\][]*])|` is the added regex alternative branch. It matches and captures

- `\\[` - a `[`
- `[^\\][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` asnd `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

The `matched` variable stands for the whole match, `group1` stands for Group 1 match. The `return group1 ? matched : mssqlFunctions[matched];` part checks if `group1` matches, and if yes,   `matched` is used to replace the match, else `mssqlFunctions[matched]`.

If you wonder why double backslashes are used, see [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066).

Comment: Man, you made my day. Was unaware how to use Regex. Perfect for me, Thanks.