# Why does regex matching up with non domain texts?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to avoid adding all site addresses including protocol or non protocol based or subdomains, i.e any sort of domain but looks like the regex is matching up with other texts as well which is wrong. I want it to only match up with domains not other things.

Code:

```
$(`[name="name"], [name="title"]`).not('[readonly]').on('focusout', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp('^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$');
    if (regex.test(value.toLowerCase())) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Take a look at the GIF:

[image]

**NOTE:** I can literally do it like this way but I don't want to:

```
$(`[name="name"], [name="title"]`).not('[readonly]').on('focusout', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp('^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$');
    if (!/\s/.test(value)) {
        if (regex.test(value.toLowerCase())) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Test your regular expression outside of your framework. You have too many things that are optional, and all that is left over is something that matches any word.

Comment: `/\./` = `new RegExp("\\.")`. `new RegExp("\.")` = `/./`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you explain your comment a bit?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, Seems like it's working now. Is this fine now? `^(http:\/\/www\\.|https:\/\/www\\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

Comment: `var regex = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, your one is also working. So seems like escaping needs to be done when passing the regex pattern to `RegExp()` right? but it seems to be working fine without passing it into `RegExp()`.

Comment: I have not advised to put the regex literal into a RegExp constructor. Read the answer in the linked thread.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks.