# JavaScript regex transpiler?

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, whitespace, transpiler

**This question is specifically about a transpiler or transpiler extension. `RegExp()` is object-creation is [massively slower and constructs the RegExp on each iteration](http://javascript-benchmark.info/NhN).**

It seems JavaScript does't permit insensitive whitespace in its regex. Is there any transpiler for JavaScript that permits something like `/x` from perl, in the Regex.

> `/x` and  `/xx` A single "/x" tells the regular expression parser to **ignore most
>       whitespace that is neither backslashed nor within a bracketed character
>       class.** You can use this to break up your regular expression into more
>       readable parts. Also, the "#" character is treated as a metacharacter
>       introducing a comment that runs up to the pattern's closing delimiter, or
>       to the end of the current line if the pattern extends onto the next line.
>       Hence, this is very much like an ordinary Perl code comment. (You can
>       include the closing delimiter within the comment only if you precede it
>       with a backslash, so be careful!)

This allows you to write something like

```
let res = name.match(/^([^\d]*?)(?:\s*[.,]\s*([0-9]+)(?: mo)?)?[.,]?$/);
```

Like this,

```
let res = name.match(/
  ^
  ([^\d]*?)                       # name
  (?:\s*[.,]\s*([0-9]+)(?: mo)?)? # age, mo
  [.,]?                           # trailing dirt
  $
 /);
```

Comment: Updated the question: This question is specifically about a transpiler or transpiler extension. RegExp() is object-creation is massively slower and constructs the RegExp on each iteration.

Comment: Just use the JS equivalent of Perl's `state re = qr/.../;`, which would be something along the lines of `persistent_var ||= new RegExp(...);`.

Comment: If you're specifically asking for a tool, then this is off topic anyway.

Comment: @ikegami that incurs a runtime compilation cost every time the pattern is encountered which is pretty substantial.

Comment: No, the cost only occurs once.

Comment: @ikegami [**benchmark**](http://javascript-benchmark.info/NhN)

Comment: My bad. That I didn't see. That would work to do what I want as a workaround. I'm going to see if I can write that into a transpiler and self-answer with that. You want to write that as an answer, I'll mark it for now.

Comment: Hmmm, did you post the wrong link? That doesn't use my solution. [Fixed benchmark](http://javascript-benchmark.info/ThN/1)

Comment: @ikegami as a side note, there are some differences from regex-literal notations and RegExp objects https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863171/124486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something exactly like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-modern-regexp