# Validate an email address always fails

Tags: javascript

Please see the code below:

```
function (string regex, string value)
{
    var regularExpression = new RegExp(regex); 
    return regularExpression.test(value);
}
```

Why does it fail? It seems to fail for everything I enter.  I got the code from here: [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) i.e. the community answer that starts: "I've slightly modified Jaymon's answer".

Comment: Don't ever use `new RegExp` unless you need to create a regex dynamically, use a literal instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance , how would I cast a string to a regular expression?

Comment: As you're doing in this question, but you really shouldn't - like I said, use literals instead (here you have many unnecessarily escaped characters)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, please see my question now.  Do you see why I need regex or is it still unnecessary? Thanks.

Comment: So you do need to create the regex dynamically - OK, see the linked canonical, you need to double-escape the backslashes

Comment: Thanks, however that link does not show how to double escape the backslashes.  I have tried this: regex.replace("\", "\\");

Comment: They need to be double-escaped in the original string, before it's passed to the function. You could also use [`String.raw`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped/55793086#55793086)

Comment: Can I use string.raw in visual studio?  I just see lots of errors with this string.  Cannot believe how difficult this is.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'd hope so - it's an ES2015 feature, which was ages ago, and code should probably be written in ESNext regardless, for ease of development. Your development environment should support it, but obsolete browsers may not, in which case you should (as always) use Babel to transpile the code to ES5 for production before serving to them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However re is a string.

Comment: How I convert a string to a regular expression?

Comment: use new RegExp(re)

Comment: if it is helpful, upvote or accept the answer, Thankyou!

Comment: I will once I get this working.  Were did you find this regex expression?

Comment: This does not work if I simply pass the string to the regex constructor.

Comment: `function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}`

Comment: Please see my original question.  The regex starts as a string.  It must be casted from a string to a regex.  Thanks.