# Confused of the type of return value of `RexExp.prototype.exec`

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I found the return value of `RexExp.prototype.exec` is weird. The returned array also contains key value pairs.

```
> RegExp('foo*','g').exec('table football, foosball')
[ 'foo',
  index: 6,
  input: 'table football, foosball',
  groups: undefined ]
```

And the returned value can pass `Array.isArray` test, and if passed to `typeof` will return `object`:

```
> Array.isArray(RegExp('foo*','g').exec('table football, foosball'))
true
> typeof RegExp('foo*','g').exec('table football, foosball')
'object'
```

So what type is it?

Is it an array with key value pairs associated? Like this:

```
> var arr = [1]
undefined
> arr.aaa = 2
2
> arr.bbb = 3
3
> arr
[ 1, aaa: 2, bbb: 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it an array with key value pairs associated?

That's exactly right. It is an normal array which has been assigned certain additional properties. Since arrays are objects, they can have arbitrary key-value pairs in addition to their usual numeric indicies, though you should almost *never* see that in normal clean code (a regular expression match is the only exception I can think of where an array object has additional non-standard properties).

(Side note: to avoid having to double-escape the (common) backslashes in a regex, consider using regex literals all the time, and only use `new RegExp` when you need to [dynamically create a pattern from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped#answer-55793086), eg `const pattern = new RegExp('foo' + myVar + 'bar')`)