# regex for url match

Tags: regex

i got two kinds of urls:

http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3/ref/somepath
 http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3

and try to math the path between '/DP/' to '/ref' or to the end of the url(if there is no '/ref' exists in the url).  in the example url mentioned above should return a string 'vk3103s3'.

and i try to using a regex like: new RegExp('/dp/(.*)(?:/ad|\$)', 'i');
it doesn't work. could somebody help to get it and tell why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `/DP/`, match anything but a slash:

```js
[
  'http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3/ref/somepath',
  'http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(
    str.match(/\/dp\/([^/]+)/i)[1]
  );
});
```

(also, [don't use `new RegExp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped) unless you need to dynamically create a pattern from a variable - you'll have to double-escape the `\`s. Better to use a regular expression literal)

If there can be multiple `/`-separated sections of the URL between the `DP` and the `/ref`, then similar to what you're doing now, lazy-repeat, and *lookahead* for `\/ref|$`. Don't use `\$`, because that would match a *literal `$` character*, rather than the end of the line:

```js
[
  'http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3/ref/somepath',
  'http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3',
  'http://somedomain/somepath/DP/vk3103s3/somethingElse/ref/somepath'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(
    str.match(/\/dp\/(.*?)(?=\/ref|$)/mi)[1]
  );
});
```