# Find string that starts with two digits and a letter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am doing a JavaScript code to hide elements on a website that does not start with a certain text.

There are a bunch of combinations that can be output in a `<span>` on the website. They all start with 2 digits and then a letter. For example:

```
76T
92Q
18H
71S
```

Sometimes the strings also contain text at the end of the line.
But right now I am trying to find out which lines contains 2 digits (no matter which) and the letter "F" afterwards. Like 92F, 35F, 19F and so on.

I am trying to use the javascript .Match but I get no results. it says no such function exists.

My code:

```
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = new RegExp("^([0-9])F(.*)");

for (var i=0; i<descriptions.length; i++) {
    if (descriptions[i].match(reg)) {
        console.log('it exists!');
    }
}
```

Basically I just want all the strings that begins with digits (0-9) and the letter F. there are NO spaces between them.

Output on website looks like this:

```
<span class="myClass">36P Wooden</span>
```

Edit:

Hide/remove the divs that does not contain this text.

```
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = /^\d{2}F/;

for (var i=0; i<descriptions.length; i++) {
    if (!descriptions[i].textContent.match(reg)) {
        descriptions[i].closest('myClass2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like collection of *elements*, and elements do not have a `.match` method. Check the `textContent` of each element instead, and consider using [regex literals instead of `new RegExp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped#answer-55793086):

```
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = /^\d{2}F/;

for (var i=0; i<descriptions.length; i++) {
    if (descriptions[i].textContent.match(reg)) {
        console.log('it exists!');
    }
}
```

```js
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = /^\d{2}F/;

for (var i=0; i<descriptions.length; i++) {
    if (descriptions[i].textContent.match(reg)) {
        console.log('it exists!', descriptions[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="myClass">36P Wooden</span>
<span class="myClass">11F something</span>
```

If you want a collection of elements which match the pattern, use `.filter` instead:

```js
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = /^\d{2}F/;

const matchingElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')]
  .filter(elm => elm.textContent.match(reg));
console.log(matchingElements);
```

```html
<span class="myClass">36P Wooden</span>
<span class="myClass">11F something</span>
<span class="myClass">22F something else</span>
```

Or, if you need all of the matching strings, use `Array.from` to map each element to its `textContent` first, before `filter`ing:

```js
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var reg = /^\d{2}F/;

const matchingStrings = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.myClass'),
  elm => elm.textContent
)
  .filter(textContent => textContent.match(reg));
console.log(matchingStrings);
```

```html
<span class="myClass">36P Wooden</span>
<span class="myClass">11F something</span>
<span class="myClass">22F something else</span>
```

To find each parent of an element which does not match, check if `.every` one of the parent's `myClass`es do not matche:

```
const parentsWithNoMatches = [...document.querySelectorAll('.myClass2')]
  .filter(parent =>
    [...parent.querySelectorAll('.myClass')]
      .every(child => !child.textContent.match(reg))
  );
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! As I only want to display the ones that does match 2 digits and F, is there any way I can hide all other objects on the page? This has to be done to the parent classes. Because there are about 6 divs, and then inside the 6th div there is this string. I'd have to go back 6 steps in the code and remove all of those nested divs prior to the string. Any idea how to do that?  EDIT: I can't use jquery to hide it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to invert the test - check if the match fails, rather than if the match succeeds. Hard to say what to do about the parent elements without seeing their code

Comment: I'd have to remove / hide the entire div with the class "myClass2" that is the parent of this string. So the closest "myClass2" (above) should be hidden.

Comment: I edited my first post here with the current code. Getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at <anonymous>:6:53`

Comment: Sounds like one of the `myClass` elements does not have a `myClass2` parent. Iterate over the parents instead

Comment: I uploaded an image of what it looks like. The parent div with class `w-50-ns w-100 ph1` is the one I want to hide or remove. https://i.imgur.com/WUS3IBf.png

Comment: Ok, so just substitute the parent class name into where `myClass2` is in the code in the answer (and the child class name into where `myClass` is)

Comment: Yes I tried it but it says undefined. The "..." should be replaced with something else? In that const

Comment: "It says undefined" isn't an error message - what exactly is the error message? No, the `...` is necessary, it spreads the collection into an array

Comment: I may be placing the const at a weird position. I placed this in the if statement of my code. Where should I place it? because I am just getting "undefined" in the console.

Comment: The last code block stands on its own - it doesn't go anywhere in particular in your Javascript, it could even be *all* of your Javascript. What exactly is the error message? `undefined` by itself won't appear in the console unless you actually log `undefined` somewhere, which isn't anywhere in the code I posted

Comment: When you type code into the console directly, the last expression evaluated will be printed on the next line of the console - unless you're *looking* for an expression, you can just ignore it. That's not an error - you now have an array of all parents which do not have one of those children.

Comment: The `.w-50-ns w-100 ph1` selector string will select children which have a tag name of `ph1`, which have a parent of a tag name of `w-100`, which have a parent with a class of `w-50`. You don't want the descendant selector here, if you want to select the elements in the picture, prefix all the class names with `.`, not with a space

Comment: Oh okay. So the `parentsWithNoMatches` contains all the items. So to hide them, I should loop through each or can I hide all at once? But how do I even target each item in the array. I only did that by targeting either id or class before. But this is an object. I can't use style.display = none on the objects

Comment: Just loop through the array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: My brain just exploded. I can loop it, but is each one in the list a document? I just make document[i].style.display = none; ? Because it dont work

Comment: No, each page/tab/`window` only has one document associated with it (the HTML page). Each item in the array is an *element*, so if you loop through it properly, setting its style like that should work fine https://jsfiddle.net/jcLvb62k/

Comment: My entire code: `var reg = /^\d{2}F/;
const parentsWithNoMatches = [...document.querySelectorAll('.w-50-ns w-100 ph1')]
 .filter(parent =>
    [...parent.querySelectorAll('.f6 fw7 silver')]
      .every(child => !child.textContent.match(reg))
  );

for (int j=0; j<parentsWithNoMatches.length; j++) {
 document[j].style.display = 'none';
}`

Comment: `int j` is invalid syntax - use `let` instead (or, preferably, use an array method like `forEach`)

Comment: Like I said in an above comment, `he .w-50-ns w-100 ph1 selector string will select children which have a tag name of ph1, which have a parent of a tag name of w-100, which have a parent with a class of w-50. You don't want the descendant selector here, if you want to select the elements in the picture, prefix all the class names with ., not with a space `

Comment: I finally did it. Holy shit. I learned something new today. It's my 3rd day with javascript. thank you!