# Regex shows match but doesn't capture

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to build a regex for my NodeJS (12.8.0) project that fetches the plaintext content of emails out of the `.eml` files of spam emails (building a simple spam filter for fun).

For this, I have written this regex:

```
[-]{14}[0-9]*\s.+[\s]+.+(?:[\s]*)([\s\S]+)[\s]{3}[-]{14}[0-9]+[\r\n]
```

When I use this regex in NodeJS, however, I get a value of `null` instead of the content of the mail.

```
const regexp = new RegExp("[-]{14}[0-9]*\s.+[\s]+.+(?:[\s]*)([\s\S]+)[\s]{3}[-]{14}[0-9]+[\r\n]");
let matches = content.match(regexp);
console.log(matches);
```

I have added my regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wMzAip/4) and it works mostly fine but interestingly enough, it tells me that it found a group `Group 1` and shows the right content... but doesn't show what lines (like with the `Full Match`).
Now to add some more interesting stuff, when I swap it to `PCRE`, it works perfectly fine (and even shows the lines).
Please do note that the demo on regex101 is containing an actual sample mail.

EDIT: As per @CertainPerformance's suggestion, I have updated the code to the following, unfortunately, this returns `false` instead of `true`:

```
const regexp = /[-]{14}[0-9]*\s.+[\s]+.+(?:[\s]*)([\s\S]+)[\s]{3}[-]{14}[0-9]+[\r\n]/;
let matches = regexp.test(content);
console.log(matches); // false
```

as well as the following, which still returns `null`:

```
const regexp = /[-]{14}[0-9]*\s.+[\s]+.+(?:[\s]*)([\s\S]+)[\s]{3}[-]{14}[0-9]+[\r\n]/;
let matches = content.match(regexp);
console.log(matches); // null
```

EDIT 2: Tested the regex in PHP and it works perfectly fine... Seems like something must be derping out...

EDIT 3: Adding the entire snippet of code in the hoped someone could spot the issue...

```
const pattern = /[-]{14}[0-9]+[\s].+[\s]+.+(?:[\s]*)([\s\S]*)[\s]{3}[-]{14}[0-9]+[\r\n]/;
const spamFolder = './datasets/spam/';
fs.readdir(spamFolder, (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);

  // Loop over each file
  files.forEach(file => {
    // Read the file
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(spamFolder + file, 'utf8');
    var matches = contents.match(pattern);
    console.log(matches); // null
  });
});
```

Comment: [Don't use `new RegExp` unless you need to construct a regex dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped#answer-55793086)

Comment: @CertainPerformance While it is good feedback, it doesn't affect the issue at all.

Comment: Sure it does, that's exactly the problem you're running into - since you're using the `new RegExp` constructor, you must double-escape the backslashes, but you aren't. Avoid `new RegExp` and the match will work, just like it does on the demo sites you're looking at (assuming that your flags and such match up).

Comment: The difference between the PCRE and JS visuals on regex101 is just that, visual only - if you see a group with PCRE enabled, and the syntax works in JS as well, that same group with the same position will be matched when you actually run the regex in JS. For some reason, regex101 doesn't highlight the different matched groups when JS is selected, but that doesn't mean the pattern isn't matching those groups. (consider it to be a regex101 visual bug)

Comment: It doesn't. affect nor solve the issue. the demo sites I'm looking at show that something is going wrong. I've tried using the literal and it doesn't change the output at all. Also, this shouldn't matter that much since the output on regex101.com is also not right. (Just take a look at it, it matches but doesn't actually capture like it does with the `PCRE` flavor)

Comment: I tried running your regex in JS (without `new RegExp`) and it appears to match as desired

Comment: I have updated my NodeJS code (using the literals and using the `.test()` method) and it now returns `false` (instead of an expected `true`).
using `content.match(regexp)` still returns `null`.

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/nukc86a0/

Comment: Hm... this is odd... it does seem to work fine in that fiddle yea...