# RegEx - Change string with format

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm still new in regex and still learning. But struggle to achieve this one.

What I want from here is to change a specific number with this format:

> (space)(number)(space) or (space)(number)(word)

This is my current code:

```
let initial = "Sample 50 This 500是是 50是 of 50是. Sample 450是是";
let regex = new RegExp("\\b50|\\b50\\D", "g");
let result = initial.replace(regex, "9");
console.log(result);
```

So from this string:

```
Sample 50 This 500是是 50是 of 50是. Sample 450是是
```

The result should be this one:

```
Sample 9 This 500是是 9是 of 9是. Sample 450是是
```

But my current result is this (**500 also changed**):

```
Sample 9 This 90是是 9是 of 9是. Sample 450是是
```

Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current pattern is that the left-side alternation `\b50` will match `50` even if there are more adjacent digits immediately to the right of the 50 - which you want to make sure there aren't.

After matching the number, negative lookahead for a digit:

```
\b50(?!\d)
```

replace with `9`:

```js
const input = "Sample 50 This 500是是 50是 of 50是. Sample 450是是";
console.log(
  input.replace(
    /\b50(?!\d)/g,
    '9'
  )
);
```

Note that since you aren't constructing the pattern dynamically, there's [no need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped#answer-55793086) for `new RegExp` - use a regex literal instead, so you don't have to double-escape the backslashes (which make it harder to read).

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, your solution works great and It has a readable code. I have noted the additional link you've added. Many thanks for the info. One quesiton, where can I find to read the docu about this one: !\d 'cause what I know is that the counterpart of \d is \D

Comment: `(?!` is the syntax for negative lookahead. Eg `foo(?!x)` will match `foo` in `fooa`, but not `foo` in `foox`. Negative lookahead for `\d` and *matching* `\D` like you're doing are pretty similar - both ensure that what was matched before isn't followed by a digit, but `\D` will mean that the non-digit character is matched as well (eg all characters in`50是` will be matched, but you only want to match the `50` part, because that's the only part you want to replace).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
(\D|^)50(\D|$)
```

- `(\D|^)` - Match Non digit character or start of string ( group1 -> $1 )
- `50` - Match `50`
- `(\D|$)` - Match Non digit character or end of string ( group2  -> $2 )

```js
let initial = "50Sample 50 This 500是是 50是 of 50是. Sample 450是是50";
let regex = /(\D|^)50(\D|$)/g
let result = initial.replace(regex, "$19$2");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @Code Maniac, your solutions works! But CertainPerformance made the first answer. But I upvoted your answer. One question though, what is the meaning of "$19$2"? Appreciated your help. Thank you!

Comment: @PepengHapon always happy to help, `$1` -> back reference to group one, `$2` back reference to group two, so this actually means `place captured value of group one 9 place captured value of group 2`