# Replace string with a value using RegExp object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Maybe I forgot how RegExp works but I tried to replace a text with empty values.

I have text like: `this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]` and I want to remove `[]` and `()`.

I want to do using RegExp object. In javascript, I'm doing like:

```js
var obj = "this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]";
var patt1 = "[\(\)\]\[]";

var regObj = new RegExp(patt1, "gi");

obj = obj.replace(regObj, "");
console.log(obj);
```

The result is still same `this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]` means nothing is replaced.

Where is my mistake ? Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/weak5ub3/

Comment: You need to escape the first `]`. Also, better to [avoid new RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793086/): instead use `/[()\][]/gi`

Comment: Try this ```console.log("this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]".replace(/[\(\)\]\[]/gi, ""))```.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That regular expression I got as string from C# action MVC (from remote server)...It's single way to send C# regex to javascript regex to be executed on client side

Comment: Then you just need to escape the first `]` (and only that, nothing else needs escaping) https://regex101.com/r/6Mk5yS/1

Comment: Your method of solving the problem is correct. The problem in your code however is that when you intended to escape the bracket characters for the regex here:
`var patt1 = "[\(\)\]\[]";` they actually got escaped in the string `patt1` first, then fed to the regex as "[()][]", which ruins it. A solution is either to escape the escape character `\` in your string:`"[\\(\\)\\]\\[]"` or construct the regex directly through the syntax: `var regObj = /[\(\)\]\[]/gi;`

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate by @CertainPerformance. However, I think that shouldn't be the case as: 1) the first suggested duplicate is about constructing the right regex, which is not the problem here (the regex works just fine). 2) the second suggested duplicate is asking why this problem exists, where the question here is asking what is the problem.

Comment: @RashadSaleh This is essentially an escaping problem. The first link shows why OP's backslashes are getting lost, and how to fix it (double-escape them), and the second shows that `]` needs to be escaped in a character set. Seems pretty clear-cut to me. OP's regex does *not* work just fine (due to the escaping issues) - see the snippet in the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance I apologize, I have referenced "the first question" for the second, and "the second question" for the first in my previous comment. Regardless, I still stand by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture group and replace

[image]

```js
var obj = "this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]";
var patt1 = /\(([^)]*)\)|\[([^\]]*)\]/gi;

obj = obj.replace(patt1, "$1$2");

console.log(obj)
```

If you want to remove `[]` and `()` irrespective of where they are, they are balanced or not, than you can simply use

```
  [\]()\[]+
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/czKm9n/1/)

---

using RegExp object, you need is to escape special characters with `\\` when you want to use regexp object

```js
var obj = "this is a blabla (32332) [XAML]";
var patt1 = new RegExp("\\(([^)]*)\\)|\\[([^\\]]*)\\]", "gi");

obj = obj.replace(patt1, "$1$2");
console.log(obj)

var pat2 = new RegExp("[\\]()\\[]+", "gi")
var secondObj = obj.replace(pat2, "$1$2")
console.log(secondObj)
```

Comment: I want RegExp object in `replace` method...

Comment: @SnakeEyes all you need is to escape with `//` when you want to use regexp object, but you should prefer regex literal unless you're trying to build a dynamic regex

Comment: @CodeManiac Your long answer is unnecessary as the question does include the right regex. Your previous comment about escaping the `/` in the string used to build the regex should instead be the answer.

Comment: @RashadSaleh thanks for your comment, but the first pattern isn't unnecessary, the question say `()` and `[]` so i tool it as it should match in balance not just any of them in any manner, so i wrote the first one, second one is just to handle the other case as op is doing, initially i had answer without regexp object as i feel thee no need of using `RegExp`, but since OP asked for that so i added as example there, yeah i agree escaping line can and should be added to answer itself

Comment: The regex `[\(\)\]\[]` is both syntactically and semantically correct. The asker has shown sufficient understanding of regex's.