# RegExp always returns null

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a RegExp in GoogleScript. The expression I have written seems to always return null.

It works fine in online RegExp testers.

```
  var number = '(123) 456-7890';
  var regExp = new RegExp("/\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d", "g");
  var a = regExp.exec(number);
  Logger.log(a);
```

Comment: [Don't use new RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793086/)

Comment: Try to use a literal regexp instead: `var regExp = /\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d/g`

Comment: Thanks. Got it working with this:
`var number = '(123) 456-7890';`
`var regex = /\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d/;`
`Logger.log(regex.test(number));`

Comment: Could be simplified as `/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/`

Comment: Does it require a closing forward slash too i.e. /someregex/?