# Angular reactive forms pattern validation not working as expected

Tags: regex, angular

I've a reactive forms validation for a password, and the pattern is the following:

```
new RegExp('^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{8,50}$');
```

My goal is to validate the string so it is:

- Between 8 & 50 characters
- Has a lower case letter
- Has an upper case letter
- Has a number
- And has a symbol

For some reason, it works like a charm, but if I enter a password that starts with a single number, the validation fails.

What am I doing wrong? 
Example passwords:

1dD5a971#  -- doesn't match

11dD5a971# -- does match

The angular code:

```
 static PASSWORD_PATTERN = new RegExp('^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{8,50}$');
this.form= fb.group({
            user: [...],
            password: ['', [Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.min(8),
                Validators.max(50),
                Validators.pattern(AddUserComponent.PASSWORD_PATTERN)
            ])]]
        };
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the pattern works right? https://regex101.com/r/tv9IIM/1

Comment: Yes, I'll update my question in a sec with the code I use.

Comment: It should work with the current code.

Comment: Are the two \ in the first grop intentional?

Comment: @chrnx Certainly yes. Though surely it can be written as `static PASSWORD_PATTERN = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{8,50}$/;`

Comment: Could you remove [ ] outside Validators.compose and make it like this  password: ['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.min(8),
                Validators.max(50),
                Validators.pattern(AddUserComponent.PASSWORD_PATTERN)
            ])]

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if it's the problem with the regex, cuz lot of online testers say it's okay. But for my application it just doesnt work.

Comment: @AhmedKesha yes, deleted (no idea why i used it like that), still not working

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Doesnt that result in a literal \ and a literal d instead of digits?

Comment: @chrnx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped

Comment: Regex is correct I tried it and it works so could you please delete  Validators.min(8),
Validators.max(50) and try

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew didn"t see he wrote it as a string. Thanks for the heads up though, didn"t know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'm not a regex expert but it may be much better if you make a multi pattern rather than just a complex pattern,the goal was for me to keep it simple as possible and you can have a different message base of the patterns.

```js
    this.form = fb.group({
      password: [
        "",
        [
          Validators.required, 
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(50),
          Validators.pattern(/[A-Z]/),
          Validators.pattern(/[a-z]/),
          Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/),
          Validators.pattern(/[!@#$]/),
         ]
      ]
    });
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-message-ayyl81)

Comment: All `{1,}`s are redundant here, consider removing.

Comment: Well, it works. In addition I can customize even more the error message to the user. Thanks dude.