# validate input field using regex

Tags: regex, reactjs, validation

I want my input to show error message when symbols or numbers entered. but when i enter symbols and numbers with letters it won't show the error message. what is the reason for it ?

```
               <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label="Name">
                    {getFieldDecorator('name',{
                            rules: [
                                {
                                  pattern:'[a-zA-Z\s]+',
                                  message: 'The input is not a valid',
                                }
                              ],
                        })(
                            <Input
                            name="name"
                        />
                        )

                        }

             </Form.Item>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use `pattern: '^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$'`, `^` and `$` will make sure the whole string should match the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why did u put // before s ? why not one ?

Comment: Try `console.log("\s")` and `console.log("\\s")`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it thanks