# Defining regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to define below regex in Javascript:

```
(\bin region\b)(?!.*\1).+?(?=<)
```

I tried like below but it looks like not working:

```
var reg = new RegExp ('(\bin region\b)(?!.*\1).+?(?=<)');
```

Although the Atom tool matches the regex in the target string, JavaScript code is returning blank.
I am using this in Azure logic app (inline code executor connector)
Anyone can help me with this?

You can see it matches the text in Atom:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a string you need to escape the backslashes.

Otherwise the backslash will escape the next character. So, writing `\b` will escape the character `b` instead use `\\b` which will escape the `\`

```
var reg = new RegExp ('(\\bin region\\b)(?!.*\\1).+?(?=<)');
```

Comment: Thanks @Som for the quick response but it still doesn't work. String is like 

Error rate is high in application  | In Region - ru</p><p><b>Enrichment Query Details: </b></p>","RenderType":"Html","Initials":null,"SubmittedByDisplayName":null,"ChangedByDisplayName":null,"IsFromConnector":true}]}}

and I am trying to get the 'In Region RU' like text.

Comment: Can you please share the string you are trying to match? @vivekmishra

Comment: There might be a problem with how you are using the regex.