# How to delete specific element nodes based on e.g. an empty attribute value of the provided markup?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, attributes, jquery-selectors

How does one delete element nodes in case the provided markup comes for example with empty attribute values like in the example below?

E.g. any image element with a missing `src` attribute needs to be deleted.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
  let src = element.src
  if (!ValidURL(src))
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});

function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/)?' + // protocol
    '((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
    '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
    '(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
    '(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locater
  if (!pattern.test(str)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid src.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image-1206-140" alt="" src="" class="ct-image img-proect" href="site.com">
<img id="image-1207-140" alt="" src="" class="ct-image img-proect" href="">
<img id="image-1207-140" alt="" src="" class="ct-image img-proect" href="">
```

Comment: `let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('src');` - there is no element with that tag name in the HTML you have shown us.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't figured out how to edit the questions here yet. This is a typo I tried with img

Comment: The console has a very clear error message for you here.

Comment: You can edit your question by pressing the edit button on the bottom left of your question. Do you want to delete it when the regex is not matched or when the attribute is empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Comment: Edited, thank you. Yes, I want to completely remove the attribute with the contents of img

Comment: Also: [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)

Comment: I was confused by this js code (

Comment: consider using [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) as starting point for validating urls instead of regexp.

Comment: _"How to delete [...] if [a certain] html attribute is empty"_ ... Start with the correct query method (e.g. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and the correct [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). Then [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) each queried element node ... `document.querySelectorAll('img[src=""]').forEach(elm => elm.remove());`

Comment: Peter Seliger thank you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"How to delete [...] if [a certain] html attribute is empty"*

Start with the correct query method (e.g. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and the correct [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). Then [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) each queried element node ... `document.querySelectorAll('img[src=""]').forEach(elm => elm.remove());`

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('img[src=""]')
  .forEach(node => node.remove());
```

```css
li:empty {
  min-height: 1.4em;
}
li:empty::after {
  content: "+++ missing image +++";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/80/60?grayscale"/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?grayscale"/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/81/61?grayscale"/></li>
  <li><img src=""/></li>
</ul>
```